# How to create git styled patches with bzr?

Tags: git, patch, bazaar

In git, when we create a patch using `git format-patch`, it adds the commit id, author's name and author's email id along with `diff` of the changes in the repository. How can I create same type of patch using bzr ? Is there any inbuilt command or there is no alternative to`bzr diff > somefilename.patch` ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/204262) it should be possible to provide a format specifier. So if `bzr-git` is installed you should go with `bzr diff -F git > somefile.patch`.

Comment: I am trying to install `bzr-git` on ubuntu 16.04 but can't find that package. Instead got `git-bzr`. Are they same?

Comment: Well,I am not 100% sure, but just give it a try :)

Comment: I installed `bzr-git` and tried to make a patch. Though it makes a git styled patch, it doesn't include author's name and email id

Answer (score 0):

To get a git-style patch including author and commit message, you can install bzr-git and use "bzr send --format=git".

E.g.:

```
bzr ci -m "Some change."
bzr send --format=git -o /tmp/git-patches ../branch-to-diff-against
```

Answer (score -1):

It's far from being completed, [but this script can generate compatible patches](https://gist.github.com/3v1n0/832522f0e1d538a68c278c467b7eb4f3).